# Python : BadZipFile: File name in directory and header differ

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I am using this method to extract this [zipfile](http://www.side.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/EXPLOITATION/DEFAULT/Infodoc/ged/viewportalpublished.ashx?eid=IFD_FICJOINT_0035542&search=).

```
r = requests.get(url)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall("Documents_zip")    #This is where the error occurs
```

And I get this error from Python :

`BadZipFile: File name in directory '2017-08-29_Cerfa_CpC_Ombi+¿res_Lac_Th+⌐sauque.pdf' and header b'2017-08-29_Cerfa_CpC_Ombi\xc3\xa8res_Lac_Th\xc3\xa9sauque.pdf' differ.`

I do not know much about the zipfile module but I found that it is too strict and that it is not necessary to check file name and header.

**How can I extract without raising the error ?**

**EDIT 1 :**

I created this function to avoid the error to raise. It just returns a boolean to indicate if whether or not, the zip extraction was run.

```
def download_zip(z, path):
    if not(z.testzip()):
        z.extractall(path)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: It looks like it might be an issue with the way that the file names and headers are encoding foreign characters - what's the path that it's struggling with? It's likely that the zip file you're using isn't correctly flagging its character encoding.

Comment: This zip file looks broken. Try to unzip it on the command line, outside Python.

Comment: @user727089 You should try to use [python's `zipfile` as a command-line argument to check validity using the `-t` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#command-line-interface) as not all utilities will reflect validity in the same way.

Comment: Great suggestion, @AriCooper-Davis! I learnt something new :)

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis this is the case, the path does not matter, if I do not specify it, it raises the same error

Comment: `z.testzip()` returned  `'2017-08-29_Cerfa_CpC_Ombi+¿res_Lac_Th+⌐sauque.pdf'`

Comment: Yeah, I think your zip is corrupt, the headers are incorrectly encoding the `é` in `Thésauque`. In which case the error is accurate.

Comment: same for `è` in `Ombrières`, can I force the encoding while extracting the files ?

Answer (score 1):

I finalised the previous function.
It extract the files of a zip into a folder namde `path`. If there is a problem, the named of the current directory is changed and the number of corrupted files is indicated.
The function also returns this number.

```
import os
import zipfile
def download_zip(z, path):
    names_files = z.namelist()
    count = 0
    for my_file in names_files:
        if my_file:
            if z.testzip():
                if not(my_file in z.testzip()):
                    try:
                        z.extract(my_file, path=path)
                    except zipfile.BadZipfile:
                        count = count +1
            else:
                z.extract(my_file, path=path)
        else:
            count = count + 1

    if count != 0:
        my_path = os.getcwd()
        parent = os.path.dirname(my_path)
        os.chdir(parent)
        os.rename(my_path, my_path + ' - ' + str(count) + ' doc du zip non extrait')
        os.chdir(my_path + ' - ' + str(count) + ' doc du zip non extrait')
    return count
```